# Makefile: store warning count into variable without using temp file

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, cmake, pipe

I would like to improve an existing Makefile, so it prints out the number of warnings and/or errors that were encountered during the build process.

My basic idea is that there must be a way to pipe the output to `grep` and have the number of occurences of a certain string in either stderr or stdout stream (i.e. "Warning:") stored into a variable that can then simply be echo'ed out at the end make command.

Requirements / Challenges:

1. **Current console output and exit code must remain exactly the same**
   That means also without even changing control characters. Dev's using the MakeFile must not recognize any difference to what the output was prior to my change (except for a nice, additional Warning count output at the end of the make process). Any approaches with `tee` i tried so far were not successful, as the color coding of stderr messages in the console is lost, changing them to all black & white.
2. **Must be system-independent**
   The project is currently being built by Win/OSX/Linux devs and thus needs to work with standard tools available out-of-the-box in most *nix / CygWin shells. Introducing another dependency such as `unbuffer` is not an option.
3. **It must be stable and free of side-effects (see also 5.)**
   If the make process is interrupted (i.e. by the user pressing `CTRL+C` or for any other reason), there should be no side-effects (such as having an orphaned log file of the output left behind on disk)
4. (Bonus) **It should be efficient**
   The amount of output may get >1MB and more, so just piping to a file and `grep`ing it will be a small performance hit and also there will be additional the disk I/O (thus unnecessarily slowing down the build). I'm simply wondering if this cannot be done w/o a temp file as i understand pipes as sort of "streams" that just need to be analysed as the flow through.
5. (Bonus) **Make it locale-independent w/o changing the current output**
   Depending on the current locale, the string to grep and count is localized differently, i.e. "Warning:" (`en_US.utf8`) or "Warnung:" (`de_DE.utf8`). Surely i could have locale switch to `en_US` in the Makefile, but that would change console output for users (Hence breaking requirement 1.), so i'd like to know if there's any (efficient) approach you could think of for this.

At the end of the day, i'd be able to do with a solid solution that just fullfills requirement 1. + 2.

If 3. to 5. are not possible to be done then i'd have to convince the project maintainers to have some changes to `.gitignore`, have the build process slightly take up more time and resources, and/or fix the make output to english only but i assume they will agree that would be worth it.

---

### Current solution

The best i have so far is:

`script -eqc "make" make.log && WARNING_COUNT=$(grep -i --count "Warning:" make.log)" && rm make.log || rm make.log`

That fulfills my requirements 1, 2 and *almost* no. 3: still, if the machine has a power-outage while running the command, `make.log` will remain as an unwanted artifact. Also the repetition of `rm make.log` looks ugly.

So i'm open on alternative approaches and improvements by anybody. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does "cmake" tag relate to pure `Makefile` question?

Comment: Have you got any measurements related to your second point? I wouldn't assume that it would be a significant bottleneck.

Comment: @Tsyvarev -  The Makefile builds a large project mainly using cmake, hence the tag. In case there is a cmake flag that will achieve something similar but w/o shell kung fu i'd be more than glad for a solution either way.

Comment: @TomFenech just checked and currently it's even less than 1MB of output, so that kind of resource consumption (at least in the current state of the repository) seems neglectable, so you have a fair point. Also updated the question to be less greedy for perfection :)

Comment: The first task could be resolved using redirecting to `tee` and using `unbuffer` utility for "fake" pipe as a terminal: https://superuser.com/questions/352697/preserve-colors-while-piping-to-tee. The other tasks are just programming/scripting tasks. For them you need to choose a language and try to write a program/script. For only catching "Warning" and "Error" words you could use `grep`, `awk` or other "base" utilities.

Comment: The question is actually a *request for a code* (a widely-useful code, this cannot be denied) and simply **too broad** for Stack Overflow Q/A format. You state several "requirements", but they are actually **separate** (not indivisible or closely-dependent) ones. A question about a **single** requirement/improvement could fit for Q/A format, but you need to perform **more elaborate research** before asking here: It could be duplicates, like with req.1 or it is needed to specify what exactly you want to parse in req.3.

Comment: *Sigh* @Tsyvarev i guess i will delete the question then and reposts based on the one liner i have so far. Was hoping someone could just have an easy answer on how to do this with a pipe. And yes, i know grep, tee, awk and alike, but i just cannot seem to figure out how to pipe them together to get back a variable with the count of occurences w/o changing original program the exit code. Surely i know how to script in several languages, but for this i need a minimal non-invasive addition to an existing Makefile.

Comment: "how to pipe them together to get back a variable with the count of occurences w/o changing original program the exit code." - From my understanding it is sufficient to `grep` (or whatever) the **whole output** of `make`  invocation and count (e.g. with `wc -l`) the number of matches. So at the end of `make` output it would be printed the number of errors/warnings/etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212210/discussion-between-philzen-and-tsyvarev).